# Port 80 on my Mac: Interpreting Results

Tags: apache

I'm using MAMP PRO on a Mac. My problems started when one of my local sites began to default to https when I try to view it in a browser (any browser). I've tried various fixes, but the problem remains, plus I get a new warning from MAMP - I need to either nix my Apple Apache service or change Apache to something other than Port 80.

Anyway, while Googling for help I discovered this Mac Terminal command: sudo lsof -i ':80'

I typed it in, and I suspect I've found the root problem. Why are Google and Amazon listed? Have they effectively hacked my Apache server? Can anyone tell me what any of this stuff means?

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google 515 [My Name] 125u IPv4 0x6270000f68f4689d 0t0 TCP 
10.0.0.138:50258->sea15s07-in-f4.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google 515 [My Name] 181u IPv4 0x6270000f69024a8d 0t0 TCP 
10.0.0.138:50341->ec2-54-84-89-183.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http 
(CLOSE_WAIT)
httpd 1267 root 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1387 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1388 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1389 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1390 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1391 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1392 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd 1402 [My Name] 4u IPv6 0x6270000f5b6af8ad 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: This might be better for SuperUser - https://superuser.com/

Comment: OK, I posted it there.